# How do you assign player names through a browser game in C# ASP.Net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, browser

## Hello, how do you assign names through a browser.

Picture this, your trying to sign up a name on a browser text box in order to join the game with your name saved in your browser as a cookie. There is possible of multiple players that can sign their names, but the game is only two players. How can I set player name that goes to my website, types in his name in a text box that gets saved into a cookies, and then he presses a join button to beings to send requests to the host to look for another player for a game.

My question would be since the player is two player, tic tac toe actually, after I have set their chosen names to a variable string, how can I assign their name to the physical player 1 and player 2 in the game, since one player goes first and one player goes second.

I though of who ever began sending requests to find another player becomes the first player (X), so who ever answers that request, responds to be the second player, the O player. Is that possible to do?

I'm running Visual Studios '08, using ASP.NET website forms. So generally using text boxes, buttons, MapPathing Stream Reader for data, and cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot to look over, but should give you a very good starting point:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MultipleUsers.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationCS2.MultipleUsers" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div style="float:left; border:1px solid gray; min-height:200px; width:40%;">
            <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="tmrUsersList" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlAjaxUserList">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrUsersList" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table style="width:100%;">
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptUsersList">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName" Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkChallenge" Enabled='<%# Eval("CanChallenge")%>' 
                                            Text="Challenge" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'
                                            OnCommand="lnkChallenge_Command" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
            Choose username:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtChosenName"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSignin" Text="Sign In" 
                OnClick="btnSignin_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplicationCS2
{
    public partial class MultipleUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private const string UserNameKey = "SitePlayer_UserName";
        private string CurrentUserName;
        private List<GameUser> lGameUsers;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie playerCookie = Request.Cookies[UserNameKey];
            CurrentUserName = (playerCookie != null ? playerCookie.Value : null);
            if (CurrentUserName != null)
            {
                // Update cache to indicate user is still online.
                Cache.Add(UserNameKey + CurrentUserName, CurrentUserName, null,
                          System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                          TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }

            lGameUsers = GetUserList();
            rptUsersList.DataSource = lGameUsers;
            rptUsersList.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnSignin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string chosenName = txtChosenName.Text.Trim();
            foreach (GameUser u in lGameUsers)
            {
                if (string.Compare(chosenName, u.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Username already in use.";
                    lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            Cache.Add(UserNameKey + chosenName, chosenName, null,
                      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
                      TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie(UserNameKey, chosenName));
        }

        protected void lnkChallenge_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        class GameUser
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public bool CanChallenge { get; set; }
        }
        private List<GameUser> GetUserList()
        {
            List<GameUser> userList = new List<GameUser>();
            foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry cacheItem in Cache)
            {
                if (cacheItem.Key.ToString().StartsWith(UserNameKey))
                {
                    string name = cacheItem.Value.ToString();
                    if (string.Compare(CurrentUserName, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
                    {
                        GameUser u = new GameUser() 
                        {
                            UserName = name,
                            CanChallenge = (CurrentUserName != null)
                        };
                        userList.Add(u);
                    }
                }
            }
            return userList;
        }
    }
}
```

To see the code in action, run the website, browse to the form, and sign in, using two different browsers.

Steps that remain for you to do are things like validating a user only signs in once, wiring up the Challenge link button, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Session["FirstPlayer"] = "true" when requester sends play request for first player and set Session["FirstPlayer"] = "false" for second player when he accepts the play request. I think this will give you information who is first and who is second player throughout their session.

You can study more about sessions on internet if you need.

You can also use Javascript global variable to store the players and their turns if you are not doing postback.